# Graph Theory: Find optimal subgraph that contains a certain node and a fixed number of nodes

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, np-complete

I have a connected graph $G$ and a real-valued function $f$ on sub-graphs $G' \subseteq G$. Given a node $n \in G$ and a positive integer $s$, I am looking for the connected subgraph $G' \subseteq G$ that minimizes $f(G')$  from all the subgraphs that contain the node $n$ and exactly $s$ nodes. More formally, I am looking for the following:

$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min} \argmin_{g\in\{G' \subseteq G | G' \text{ is connected},\  n\in G',\ |G'|=s\}}\ {f(g)}\enspace .$$

Is there any efficient exact solution to this problem or is this NP-hard? If the latter is the case, is there any polynomial-time approximation to the exact solution?

Comment: If $f$ can be an arbitrary function, then it is not even in $\mathsf{NP}$, in particular to prove that some subgraph $G'$ is indeed the global minimum you have to enumerate all the graphs with desired properties. (And I assume that by _real value_ you mean some approximation like `double`, because true real values are quite hard to deal with by themselves).

Comment: I think it makes more sense if $f(G')$ is defined as something like $\sum_{v\in V_{G'}}f(v)$, or you can make $f$ a fixed function. Otherwise a poly-time solution can be given by simply exhausting all possible subgraphs since $f$ has to be encoded in the input.

Comment: Yes, by real-valued I actually mean double-valued. ;-)
Unfortunately $f$ cannot be defined like the above, as it - besides some other constraints - should minimize the color variance of the nodes in $G'$ (each node has an assigned color).

Comment: @Sven So your $f$ function is a specified one. You should make the definition of $f$ clear in your question.